# Contains and append to the column cell

Tags: pandas

```
if df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC") , to append apple to ColumnA.
```

eg: ColumnA -> "ABC Company" , after running the code ColumnA -> "ABC Company apple"

May I know what is the fastest way to achieve this, if i dont wanna use for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['ColumnA'] = np.where(df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"),\
                df.ColumnA + 'myvalue', df.ColumnA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) what is same fast like `np.where` because processing only matched rows:

```
df.loc[df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"), 'ColumnA'] += ' apple'
```

**Performance**: For 400k rows, 50% matched

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':['ABC Company','ABC','temp', 'DDD']* 100000})
print (df)

In [82]: %timeit df['ColumnA'] = np.where(df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"), df.ColumnA + 'myvalue', df.ColumnA)
329 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [83]: %timeit df.loc[df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"), 'ColumnA'] += ' apple'
323 ms ± 6.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If there is less matched values, here 25% then `loc` is faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':['ABC Company','ee','temp', 'DDD']* 100000})
#print (df)

In [89]: %timeit df['ColumnA'] = np.where(df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"), df.ColumnA + 'myvalue', df.ColumnA)
306 ms ± 5.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [90]: %timeit df.loc[df.ColumnA.str.contains("ABC"), 'ColumnA'] += ' apple'
269 ms ± 4.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```